# Accessing volume checkbox of a camera in the Stereoscopy section

Tags: python, stereoscopy

Is there a way to check/uncheck the volume checkbox in the stereoscopy tab in the settings of a camera via the Blender Python API?

[image]

Update:

```
    bpy.context.space_data.show_stereo_3d_cameras = False
    bpy.context.space_data.show_stereo_3d_convergence_plane = False
    bpy.context.space_data.show_stereo_3d_volume = True
```

I saw in the console that these are the properties I want to change. But I can´t find a way to change them using the Blender API because the properties are read-only according to the documentation. Anyone an idea on how to change them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cycle through the `areas` of the `bpy.context.screen` untill you find an area with the `type` **`VIEW_3D`**.

```
import bpy

areas = bpy.context.screen.areas

for area in areas:
    if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
        area.spaces[0].show_stereo_3d_cameras           = False
        area.spaces[0].show_stereo_3d_convergence_plane = False
        area.spaces[0].show_stereo_3d_volume            = True
        area.spaces[0].stereo_3d_volume_alpha           = 0.5
```

Comment: `area.spaces[0]` is aka `area.spaces.active`.  Also noticed 2.8 uses `area.ui_type` (in UI to switch spaces), yet still retains the `area.type` as above.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the latter. Is type deprecated? Could you correct it?

Comment: Not sure at the moment either.  Noticed it today hovering over the enum, seemed worth mentioning fwiw.

Comment: This (https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area) is the Blender 2.8 API documentation for `bpy.context.screen.areas`. I don´t see any deprecated comments on the methods @Leander mentions.

Solution works perfectly for me :)

Comment: On `ui_type`  is how for instance area type of  'NODE_EDITOR' is opened to show material, scene or custom nodes in UI.  Typing `C.area.ui_type = 'XXX'` in python console will list the options in lieu of docs linked above .  Yes the solution works "perfectly" , that's why I upvoted it, wasn't suggesting it didn't simply giving a heads up on something new.